# get addition without button click

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Can anyone help me to get the addition of Basic Salary and Allowance I and insert it in Total Day Rate without clicking a button. here's my php code.
Here's a [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh8KH.jpg) of my UI.
**Code** :

```
<?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

        $db = mysql_select_db("laboursalary", $connection);
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];
    $LabourSupplier = $_POST['LabourSupplier'];
    $Home = $_POST['Home'];
    $Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
    $BasicSalary = $_POST['BasicSalary'];
    $Allowance1 = $_POST['Allowance1'];
    $Allowance2 = $_POST['Allowance2'];
    $DayRate = $_POST['$DayRate'];
    $OTrate = $_POST['OTrate'];
    if($ID !=''||$Name !=''){

    $query = mysql_query("insert into attendance(ID, Name, Location, Category,LabourSupplier,Home,Mobile,BasicSalary,Allowance1,Allowance2,DayRate,OTrate) values ('$ID','$Name','$Location','$Category','$LabourSupplier','$Home','$Mobile','$BasicSalary','$Allowance1','$Allowance2','$DayRate','$OTrate')");
    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";   
    }

    }

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

After I enter the values for Basic Salary and Allowance 1, I want to get the addition of those two in Day Rate automatically.
this is my **HTML** code.

```
<form id="details" action="" method="POST">

    <fieldset> ID:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="ID" value="" />
      </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Name:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Name" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Location:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Location" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Category:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Category" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Labour Supplier:
     <input class="input" type="text" name="LabourSupplier" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Telephone:
     <input class="input" type="text" name="Home" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Mobile:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Mobile" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Basic Salary:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="BasicSalary" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Allowance I:
    <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance1" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Allowance II:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance2" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Total Day Rate:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="DayRate" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>OT Rate:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="OTrate" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Insert</button>
      <button onclick="goBack()" name="Back" type="back" id="details-back">Back</button>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
```

Comment: Hi, i do not get your question, what you're doing right now? What you want to achieve?

Comment: Use Javascript/Jquery to get the value from both the fields & put the SUM of both the values that in the  ```Total Day Rate``` field. It's simple. Try to make your hand bit dirty.

Comment: Add your HTML Code as well, and you need javascript/jQuery to do it for you.

Comment: after i enter values in Basic Salary and Allowance 1, i want to get the addition automatically of those two, in Total Day rate box.

Comment: `get the addition of Basic Salary and Allowance I and insert it in Total Day Rate`....  Something like this:  ` $result = $BasicSalary + $Allowance1;` `$query = mysql_query("insert into attendance (DayRate) values ('$result')"); if($query!=false){  echo something about the success  }else{ mysql errno etc... }` Honestly though, you can **not** process php without refreshing the page, so you may be looking for an angular/JS/JQuery method to push the value into your array before you submit it using a post method.

Comment: **suggestion**: user **mysqli_\*** function instead of **mysql_\*** , as **mysql_\*** functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, your **HTML** code should be like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="details" action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset> ID:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="ID" value="" />
      </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Name:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Name" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Location:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Location" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Category:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Category" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Labour Supplier:
     <input class="input" type="text" name="LabourSupplier" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Telephone:
     <input class="input" type="text" name="Home" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Mobile:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Mobile" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Basic Salary:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="BasicSalary" value="0" id="bassal" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Allowance I:
    <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance1" value="0" id="all1" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Allowance II:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance2" value="0" id="all2" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Total Day Rate:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="DayRate" value="" id="DayRate" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>OT Rate:
     <input class="input" type="number" name="OTrate" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Insert</button>
      <button onclick="goBack()" name="Back" type="back" id="details-back">Back</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
<script >
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#bassal').on('input', function() {
            $('#DayRate').val(parseInt($('#bassal').val()) + parseInt($("#all1").val()) + parseInt($("#all2").val()));
        });
        $('#all1').on('input', function() {
            $('#DayRate').val(parseInt($('#bassal').val()) + parseInt($("#all1").val()) + parseInt($("#all2").val()));
        });
        $('#all2').on('input', function() {
            $('#DayRate').val(parseInt($('#bassal').val()) + parseInt($("#all1").val()) + parseInt($("#all2").val()));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've added jQuery, that does your work, and you don't need to do addition on PHP side.

Comment: when you change **BasicSalary** or **Allowance1** or **Allowance2**, it will automatically calculate sum of those three and put it into **DayRate**.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would be done using a submit for post as these are all _POST values... Though to accomplish this without pressing a button would be JS/Angular/J Query/AJAX...

```
....
$BasicSalary = $_POST['BasicSalary']; 
$Allowance1 = $_POST['Allowance1'];
$Allowance2 = $_POST['Allowance2'];
$DayRate = $_POST['$DayRate'];
$OTrate = $_POST['OTrate'];

//Set a new variable with the addition of the two `Basic Salary` and  `Allowance 1` 
//for the insertion into your column `dayRate`   
$adustedDayRate = $BasicSalary + $Allowance1;
if($ID !=''||$Name !=''){

    if($query != false){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `attendance` (ID, Name, Location, Category,LabourSupplier,Home,Mobile,BasicSalary,Allowance1,Allowance2,DayRate,OTrate) values ('$ID','$Name','$Location','$Category','$LabourSupplier','$Home','$Mobile','$BasicSalary','$Allowance1','$Allowance2','$adustedDayRate','$OTrate')");
    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
    }esle{ $_SESSION['err'] = "ERROR: ".--- MySQL error handle here --- }
}
else{
echo "Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";   
}

}

mysql_close($connection);
```

**Using Angular**, you could place a placeholder element in your form input for `DayRate, then add the call back for the ng-model element for the two inputs you wish to add. Something like this here:

```
<div ng-app="">

<p>BasicSalary : <input type="number" ng-model="BasicSalary" placeholder="Basic Salary"></p>

<p>AllowanceI  : <input type="number" ng-model="AllowanceI" placeholder="Allowance I"></p>

<p>DayRate   : <input type="number" ng-model="DayRate" placeholder="{{BasicSalary -- AllowanceI}}"></p>
```

Your code would look like:

```
<fieldset> Basic Salary:
 <input class="input" type="number" ng-model="BasicSalary" name="BasicSalary" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset> Allowance I:
<input class="input" type="number" ng-model="Allowance1" name="Allowance1" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>Allowance II:
 <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance2" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>Total Day Rate:
 <input class="input" type="number" name="DayRate" placeholder="{{ BasicSalary -- Allowance1 }}" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

Here is a working fiddle of the angular method, simply add the angular library to your server using composer or hosted links, no additional JS is required with the Angular library elements. You can change the value of DayRate as the two other combining inputs are being input.
https://jsfiddle.net/qkpfb90o/1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this.

```
<form id="details" action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset> ID:
        <input class="input" type="text" name="ID" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Name:
        <input class="input" type="text" name="Name" value="" />
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset> Location:
       <input class="input" type="text" name="Location" value="" />
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset> Category:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Category" value="" />
   </fieldset>
  <fieldset> Labour Supplier:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="LabourSupplier" value="" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset> Telephone:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Home" value="" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>Mobile:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="Mobile" value="" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset> Basic Salary:
      <input class="input" type="number" name="BasicSalary" value="" id="BasicSalary" onkeyup="doSum()"/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset> Allowance I:
      <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance1" value="" id="Allowance1" onkeyup="doSum()"/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>Allowance II:
      <input class="input" type="number" name="Allowance2"  />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>Total Day Rate:
      <input class="input" type="number" name="DayRate" value="" id="DayRate" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>OT Rate:
      <input class="input" type="number" name="OTrate" value="" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Insert</button>
      <button onclick="goBack()" name="Back" type="back" id="details-back">Back</button>
  </fieldset>
```

```
<script>
function doSum() {
    var Allowance1 = isNaN(document.getElementById('Allowance1').value) ? document.getElementById('Allowance1').value : 0;
    var BasicSalary = isNaN(document.getElementById('BasicSalary').value) ? document.getElementById('BasicSalary').value : 0;
    var tot = parseInt(Allowance1) + parseInt(BasicSalary);
    document.getElementById('DayRate').value = tot;
}
</script>
```